# Autodesk Forge System.OutOfMemoryException, can we get more memory?

Tags: autodesk-forge

One of the queries we run in our plugin requires a lot of memory. Would it be possibe to start up RCE and get more memory allocated for this run?

```
[05/07/2021 20:56:46] Start GetAllMaterialsForElements
[05/07/2021 20:59:09] ERROR: The process memory limit exceeded (4276).
[05/07/2021 20:59:09] Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. -  -    at Autodesk.Revit.DB.PlanarFace..ctor(GFace* pGFace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error about "process memory limit exceeded" happens when calling Revit API for large model, but there is no choice to specify different RCE instance at this moment.

While this may help in future, we are thinking about upgrading the instance, it's in the plan but no exact timeline.